# Localhost code editor in Google Chrome tab - like Notepad++?

Tags: browser, google-chrome, localhost, offline

I looked into very many Google Chrome extensions and apps in order to find one that matches the following requirements:

- runs in a Google Chrome tab
- editor for any code, PHP, CSS, HTML
- can load and save files (on my computer) and create new ones
- works with local files on my computer

Is there any? kodingen, cloud9, shiftedit does not seem to make it on the localhost.

Comment: http://tiny.cc/code-editor satisfies  some of your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe SourceKit will do?

SourceKit is an extension to your Google Chrome browser which runs in a separate tab. The files are stored in your Dropbox account, so not only can you access the files from your computer - you can access them from anywhere! It uses syntax highlighting like Notepad++ for a limited number of languages (you said php, css, and html - they are all supported). It can load, save, and edit text files locally on your computer if you install the Dropbox Desktop Application. This will also synchronize the files with your online account and thereby make them accessible from anywhere in the world.

That sounded more like a salesman's advertisement than intended.

Both [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and [SourceKit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg) are free.

There are four catches as far as I can see:

- Dropbox "only" offers 2GB for free, however, you can upgrade at any time if you're willing to pay.
- Dropbox Desktop will only synchronize one folder (and all of its contents), but that's really not any different from a web site.
- SourceKit will not debug your code, but will it highlight wrong syntax(only for certain languages).
- **EDIT** Does not work offline.

I've tried it out, and it works well.

Comment: I tested it out and it works. The downsides I found was: 1. It takes a few seconds before it downloads the saved file to my computer. 2. It can only sync one folder like you said. I might need to create another dropbox account with only my WAMP-folder.

Answer (score 2):

### [Sympathy Editor](https://github.com/captn3m0/sympathy/)

Sympathy uses the npapi-file-io plugin mentioned in [an answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859817/368328) to allow you to edit local files.

#### Pros

- Allows you to edit local files
- Full syntax highlighting
- Bookmark local files for easy access

#### Cons

- Uses npapi plugin to read files, which means it has access to all your data
- Unavailable on Chrome Webstore
- Still under development
- Only works on linux/windows as of the moment (not in mac)

If you are interested, you can see the [README](https://github.com/captn3m0/sympathy/blob/master/README.mkd), or [Manual](https://github.com/captn3m0/sympathy/blob/master/manual.mkd) on github.

[image: Screenshot of this file]

Disclosure: I'm the primary developer of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Don't any of these extensions you have mentioned work with the file:/// protocol? They will work for the http:// protocol only if you are going to edit files inside your local webserver.

Instead of writing http://localhost/(...) you write file:///(...), where (...) is the full path.

In UNIX systems it is file:///home/jens/file.txt. In Windows it should be file:///C:\(...).

Comment: I think you meant file:///, not file:// (yes, file:/// on every OS). I think it originates from *NIX's / path, but on windows it's still file:///C:\[...].

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There's no extension for editing local files.</strike>

But you can write one!

Acesses to local filesystem cannot be done using Chrome's Extension API.

But you can use HTML5's [File API (which is draft)](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/) or [Local Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). <strike>If none of these storage methods sufficient for you, you can build a [NPAPI Plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html). Chrome supports NPAPI Plugins. There's also a project called [npapi-file-io](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io) in Google Code which aims to access local files from Google Chrome Extension context.</strike>

**Edit:**

Now, [there's one usable editor, Symphaty](https://github.com/captn3m0/sympathy/). You can use Capt.Nemo's Symphaty editor.

**Edit 2:**

NPAPI plugins are [phased out from Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) since version 42. The only alternative would be to use a wrapper native app and communicate using [Native Messaging API](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html).

Comment: I made [sympathy editor](https://github.com/captn3m0/sympathy/) along these lines using NPAPI-file-io.

Answer (score 0):

@Berk Demirkir may be right.

Here are the resources I found that may be of use;

[32 Google Chrome Extensions For Smart Designers](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/google-chrome-extensions-web-developers-designers/)

[Chrome Web Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbmlldeibipeppiabbdjajcneipfbocm) No. 7 on the above list

Answer (score 0):

ShiftEdit can be used to [work locally](https://shiftedit.net/blog/working-locally), you will need to have XAMPP or equivalent installed.